# with a dd of an entire disk can you restore only a specific partition

Tags: linux, dd

I have a full dd of my hard disk which has 3 partitions, how can I using this image only restore a specific partition?

Comment: The laziest way is just to restore the whole thing and then extract the partition you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop mount individual partitions. I have done this quite a few times but this blog and similar one you can find on net give you clear step.

http://madduck.net/blog/2006.10.20:loop-mounting-partitions-from-a-disk-image/

The key is to find the offset of your partition in the image.

This man page for bochs is likely more permanent

http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/loop-device-usage.html

Comment: By the way, partimage is a more efficient way of backing up partitions.

Answer (score 3):

`kpartx` will allow you to use device mapper to map the partitions within the image to distinct device nodes.